# Numpy: how to set column[index:]=value, for each column, for an array of different indices?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have an array:

```
my_array = np.random.normal(size=(5,3))
print(my_array)

[[ 0.45110035 -1.08385534  1.2126054 ]
 [ 1.51280316  0.4308235  -0.31839059]
 [-0.00348102 -0.50814392  0.00734745]
 [-0.63701191  0.95413945 -1.40480595]
 [-1.66723431 -0.52822503 -1.14282036]]
```

And a list of indices of the same length as the number of columns:

```
my_indices = np.array([3, 1, 2])
```

For each column in `my_array`, I want to get the corresponding index from `my_indices`, and set that element and all subsequent elements of that column to some new value. In other words the result would look like:

```
my_new_array = np.something(my_array, my_indices, 23)
print(my_new_array)

[[ 0.45110035 -1.08385534  1.2126054 ]
 [ 1.51280316  23.0       -0.31839059]
 [-0.00348102  23.0        23.0      ]
 [ 23.0        23.0        23.0      ]
 [ 23.0        23.0        23.0      ]]
# i.e.:
# col[3:]=23  col[1:]=23  col[2:]=23
```

What is the most numpy-ish way to achieve this? I know I could do it with a simple for-loop, but that's bad practice for numpy. My intuition is that there's probably some clever fast way to do it through broadcasting and vectorizing, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting or selecting one item from each column is easy:

```
In [10]: arr = np.ones((5,3),int)
In [11]: b = np.array([3,1,2])
In [12]: arr[b, np.arange(3)] = 0
In [13]: arr
Out[13]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

But setting a slice per column is trickier.  The simplest is to just iterate on columns.

```
In [14]: for i,j in enumerate(b):
    ...:     arr[j:, i] = 0
    ...:     
In [15]: arr
Out[15]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Another is to set up a mask using a comparison of `b` with `np.arange(5)`.  That's faster, but not as intuitive.  I have to rethink the approach each time.

```
In [16]: mask = np.arange(5)[:,None]>=b
In [17]: mask
Out[17]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
In [18]: arr[mask] = 2
In [19]: arr
Out[19]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

Comment: Ah! The `np.arange` approach is very simple, but only in hindsight. Thanks!